# How to read flat files with Spring-Batch when lines are interdependent

Tags: spring-batch, flat-file

I have flat files to read with spring-Batch. Each line is 600 characters long and "columns" sizes are fixed.

In this file, there are 4 templates:

- line starting with 00 is header
- lines starting with 10 are data
- lines starting with 20 are sub-data of lines 10
- line starting with 99 is footer

In header line (00) and footer line (99), there is the number of data lines (10). In data lines (10), there is the number of associated sub-data lines (20).

The file looks like (I added spaces just for the example):

`00 Hello 3 foo ...    // here 3 means 3 data lines
...
10 id123 5 foo ...    // here 5 means 5 sub-data
20 id123 otherid456 foo...
20 id123 otherid789 foo ...
20 id123 otherid012 foo ...
20 id123 otherid345 foo ...
20 id123 otherid645 foo ...
...
10 id456 2 foo ...    // here 2 means 2 sub-data
...
99 by 3 foo ...`

Also, data lines (10) and sub-data lines (20) share a common id ("id123" in the example).

Of course, the number of specified lines can be zero. In this cas, there is the data line (10) but no associated sub-data line (20).

My question is about the fact that lines are interdependent. What is the best way to read that kind of file? What would you recommend?

Thx.

Comment: Please check if https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#multiLineRecords works for your requirments.

Comment: I think it does the work. Thx.

Comment: Great to know. Pls upvote so ppl know as well